# Sort order on secondary floating point index in HBase

Tags: java, floating-point, indexing, hbase, endianness

I'm trying to implement something like a search engine in HBase. Aside from how good an idea this really is (finding out is the reason to do this), I need to support a 'range query' on floating point values. Creating an inverted index would be the default way to do this, mapping floating point value to row key in a separate data structure. For this to work as index, however, I need to be able to issue a Scan from the low point of the range to the high point (at least, that's my current theory).

As HBase orders by byte array, starting a row key with a floating point won't get me a usable index, if only as the very first bit in the byte-representation of a floating point number is 1 for negative values and 0 for positive values (which is out of float value order). As such, I'm at a loss on how to create this index.

Am I taking an idiotic approach to this, or will one of the following work better?

Convert the floating points to a duo of integer values, one before and one after the decimal point:

```
BigDecimal[] doubleValue = 
    new BigDecimal((Double) value).divideAndRemainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
byte[] valueBytes = new byte[16];
System.arraycopy(Bytes.toBytes(doubleValue[0].longValue()), 0, valueBytes, 0, 8);
System.arraycopy(Bytes.toBytes(doubleValue[1].longValue()), 0, valueBytes, 8, 8);
```

Somehow convince HBase to use a custom comparator for the row keys (no idea how to do this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different approach to serialize your values into byte[] if you want hbase to sort them properly.  Check out https://github.com/ndimiduk/orderly.
Alternately, I believe the Lily library can also do this.

Comment: That implementation seems quite simpler than mine, thanks for the find :)